# Threads and interrupt

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

I have the following code

```
package threads;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Threads extends Thread implements Runnable {

    private final List<Thread> threadList = new ArrayList<>();
    private String f, l;
    private Thread greetings1, greetings;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] elements = { "Tim", "Fred", "Jeff", "Scott" };
        Threads t = new Threads();
        for (String e : elements) {
            t.threadL(e);

            t.threadR(e);
        }

        for (int index = 0; index < t.threadList.size(); index++) {
            // blank at the moment

        }
    }

    public void threadR(String f) {
        greetings = new Thread(f);

        Thread greetingsFromFred = new Thread(greetings) {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Main Thread: " + i + " " + f);
                        Thread.sleep(5000);

                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        System.out.println("Main thread interrupted.");

                    }
                    System.out.println("Main thread exiting.");
                }
            }
        };
        greetingsFromFred.start();
    }

    public List<Thread> threadL(String l) {
        greetings1 = new Thread(this);

        this.l = l;
        greetings1.start();

        threadList.add(greetings1);

        return (threadList);

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        greetings.interrupt(); // interrupt greetings thread here <-------

        System.out.println("Greetings from " + l + "! threadL");

    }
}
```

when threadL runs i want to interrupt threadR from running and therefore cause the

```
 System.out.println("Main thread interrupted.");
```

to be printed from threadR

I have highlighted in my code where the interrupt should take place

```
 greetings.interrupt();  //interrupt greetings thread here <-------
```

why is the interruption not working as it currently stands?

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your code; it's currently unreadable.

Comment: What do you mean by " the interruption not working as it currently stands"?

Comment: "extends Thread implements Runnable" I suggest you choose between one of those.

Comment: remove the "extends Thread", use only implements Runnable as you are only @Overriding on the run() function.

Comment: @DanielNetzer, for correct usage, you need to override Thread's `run()` method as well. It really depends on whether he needs to run a block of code, or run a block of code in a new thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program is a bit of a maze of thread objects. Let's try to follow it from `main`.

In `main`, you create an object `t` which is of type `Threads`. This means it's a `Thread` and a `Runnable`.

Then, for each of your string, you run `t`'s `threadL` and `threadR` with that string as parameter.

Nowhere in `main` do you actually start `t`, or even run its `run` method directly.

Then, in `threadR` you create a new, empty `Thread` and assign it to `greetings`.

You then use that new empty `Thread` (greetings) as a `Runnable` that's being passed to a new `Thread` object that also has its `run` method overridden. This is rather futile. In any case, `greetingsFromFred` is started, and will run the loop. But `greetings` still contains that empty `Thread` that has nothing to do with the `greetingsFromFred` thread.

In `threadL` you create yet another `Thread`, to which you pass the current `Thread` (which is `t` in `main`) as its runnable. You then finally start it. It will try to interrupt the thread in `greetings`, but as we said, that's an inactive empty thread that was never started.

Your structure should be a lot less convoluted than that. As much as possible, use just `Runnable` objects for things that should be executed. Thus, `Threads` itself shoudld be a `Runnable`, and `threadR` should probably be fixed to something like this:

```
public void threadR(String f) {

    Runnable greetingsFromFred = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Main Thread: " + i + " " + f);
                    Thread.sleep(5000);

                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Main thread interrupted.");

                }
                System.out.println("Main thread exiting.");
            }
        }
    };

    greetings = new Thread(greetingsFromFred, f);
    greetings.start();
}
```

This way, `greetings` will be a `Thread` which will run that loop that you have created *in a `Runnable`*, and also have the name `f`.

Note, though: since you don't actually stop the loop in your `catch` clause, you won't exit the loop when the thread is interrupted, and you'll possibly have the "Exiting" message printed more than once, depending on when the interrupt hits the loop.

Comment: @ RealSkeptic I am experimenting with Threads - i am fairly new to threads and just looking at the different things i can do. Your guide was very useful to me in understand what is happening, and that i hadnt yet started the greetings thread which was the main problem. Great answer from you

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to interrupt `greetingsFromFred`. This is the thread that is being started and actually run. The thread `greetings` is never run. Is is only passed as runnable to the other thread. Why do you even pass some other thread in a thread's constructor? This whole design is very fishy. I think you got confused about thread/runnable and when and how to use one.

Answer (score 0):

The thread you want to interrupt is called `greetingsFromFred` not `greetings` so this  change will work, provided you make `greetingsFromFred` visible.

```
       greetingsFromFred.interrupt();  //interrupt greetings thread here <-------
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted by others, there are several issues here.

## Unnecessary Inheritance

Your class `Threads` has a `run()` method that interrupts whatever thread is assigned to `greetings`, but neither `R` and `L` inherit that `run()` method. `R` extends `Thread` and overrides `run()`, and `L` just extends `Thread` without overriding. That structure makes no sense.

Given that, it seems that this `run()` method should be overridden by `L`.

If you make that happen, then there is no need for `Threads` to override `Thread` or implement `Runnable`. You can take that off entirely and have `R` and `L` each override `Thread` themselves (using the `Thread(String)` constructor).

```
public class Threads {
...
    public List<Thread> threadL(String l) {
        greetings1 = new Thread(l) {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                greetings.interrupt(); // interrupt greetings thread here <-------
                System.out.println("Greetings from " + l + "! threadL");
            }
        ...
    }
}
```

So now `threadR()` creates and starts a new `Thread` that will be interrupted, and `threadL()` creates and starts a new `Thread` that will interrupt, and `Threads` just exists for the `main()` method and the creation/starting of threads in `threadR()` and `threadL()`. Cleaner.

## Interrupting the Wrong Thread

As noted by others, you have this unnecessary variable, `greetingsFromFred`, that just complicates matters. Everything you do for `greetingsFromFred` you should instead do for `greetings` (except the constructor).

```
public void threadR(String f) {
    greetings = new Thread(f) {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            ...
        }
    greetings.start();
}
```

## Race Condition on `greetings`

Here's the most subtle part, IMO. You're using the static variable `greetings` to hold the current `Thread` object `R` that the current `L` is supposed to interrupt. But there's no coordination between those two threads. There's no reason to believe that each `L` is going to see a unique `R` in `greetings`. And that's a *Very Bad Thing*. What you need to do is make `greetings` `volatile`, then make `R` wait until `greetings` is null before assigning it and make `L` wait until `greetings` is not null before interrupting it.

```
private volatile Thread greetings;
...
public void threadR(String f) {
    while (greetings != null);
    greetings = new Thread(f) {
...
public void threadL(String l) {
    Thread greetings1 = new Thread(l) {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (greetings == null);
...
```

Note the use of `while(...);`. The trailing semicolon is an empty statement. This construct just says to keep checking the condition until it's false, then continue. Since `R` never proceeds until it has a `null` and then sets it, and `L` never proceeds until it has a `non-null` and then nulls it, they will always remain in sync.